# Filter on Custom Fields

Tags: azure-devops

We have added 5 custom fields but are unable to find a way to filter based on data in these fields. Anyone any ideas or resolved this?

Custom fields have been added in VSTS using customization under Process settings.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment there is no support for this on Boards and Backlogs. Queries as described by Marian might be your best bet. There is an open ticket for it.  Please vote to (hopefully) prioritize this.

> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/606538/add-the-ability-to-filter-boards-by-custom-fields.html
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1270736/how-can-i-add-my-custom-filter-columns-in-boards-a.html

Answer (score 1):

The feature is available in VSTS.

Below is the detail steps to add a custom field and filter query work items based on the custom field (you can compare with your steps):

#### 1. Add a custom field

In the Process page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_admin/_process) -> Processes Tab -> select the inherited process -> select the work item type you want to add a field (such as PBI in the example) -> New field -> specify the field you add (it's `newField` in the example).

[image]
[image]

#### 2. Query work items based on the custom field

Go to a project which you are using the inherited process -> Work Hub -> Queries Tab -> specify the custom field to filter the work items.

[image]